# totally bounded equals topologically bounded in family of holomorphic functions on region G?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck on the following problem: Show that for a set $F \subset H(G)$ the following are equivalent conditions:

a) F is totally bounded (or normal)

b) For every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a number $c > 0$ such that $\{cf : f \in F \} \subset B(0, \epsilon)$.

Here H(G) is the set of holomorphic functions on a region G in the complex plane, and $B(0,\epsilon)$ is the ball centered at 0 with radius $\epsilon$ in H(G). (we use the metric given by the infinite sum involving an exhaustion of compact sets for G) The forward direction (a to b) is pretty easy. For the other direction, I was trying to use the fact that a set is totally bounded if and only if it is compact in a metric space, so I was looking at the closure of F. I thought it had something to do with the fact that the closure of F is bounded in H(G). I was trying to use Montel's theorem and show that the closure of F is also locally bounded, but I'm not sure how to do that. Am I on the right track? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: b) with $\epsilon =1$ shows that $F$ is locally bounded, hence normal.

Comment: My apologies, but I don't follow. How does setting epsilon = 1 imply that F is locally bounded?

Comment: Never mind, finally figured it out.